# Clarification of the process behind healing?

Tags: healing, deathwatch

I've read the section on healing in Deathwatch several times, and I can't quite seem to get my head around it.  It says you can only attempt to heal once per wound, but it doesn't really seem to clarify how that works.  Does it mean I can only heal a character as many times as he's been hit?  Or as many times as he has hit points?  Do I have to somehow track how much damage was done per each hit, and only heal that amount?  I'd appreciate it if someone gave me a rundown on exactly how the healing works under that system;  we're completely lost here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, the healing section is poorly worded.

Ok, Humor aside... The wording of the medicae skill (p.102) is not well done.

I've interpreted it in DH and DW, based upon experience with WFRP 1E and 2E, to mean this:

**Method 1**

When you are wounded, you can receive first aid once. If wounded again after receiving first aid, you can receive 1st aid again.

EG1.1:
*Jook has been hit 4 times, and of his 22 wounds and 70T, he's taken a total of 14 points. He's still lightly damaged, and so will get back the medic's Int Bonus on a successful first aid test.*

**Method 2**

A more literal interpretation would be track each individual hit's damage as a separate number, and each hit can only be healed to 0. It's more work, and logic dictates that a given wound can only be healed to down to 0, tho it's not explicit in the rules that way.

EG1.2:
*Jook has been hit 4 times, and of his 22 wounds and 70T, he's taken a total of 14 points, with the individuals being 5, 4, 3, 2. He's still lightly damaged, and so will get back the Int Bonus on a successful first aid test on each wound, but you can't heal past the wound being worked on.*

**Method 3**

Limit 1st aid to once per battle. Many GM's I've talked to do this, but it fails to match the rules.

**Commentary**

Either is workable. Given the earlier editions, however, it's *easiest* to GM if you use method 1 or 3.

Note that 
Method 1 makes first aid faster, but less effective over all. A medic can field process a dozen guys in a couple minutes.
Method 2 makes first aide slower, often much so, but means the guy with a dozen small wounds is going to be nearly healed after a half-hour with the medic.
Method 3 is the easiest to run, but it isn't the rules. It's very similar to Method 1.

Some Critical hits also require first aid to stop bleeding. Some GM's allow a bleeding stop roll to heal a point of damage as well. Others don't; the wording on p.260 implies strongly that it's a 3rd application of Medicae, and not covered on p.102. I don't allow it to heal a wound as well.

As an option, if using option 1, you might allow adding degrees of success to the amount healed, while with Option 2, it would often be moot.

Note also, based upon collating pages 262 and 102:

Lightly Damaged: total damage taken (after armor and toughness reductions) is less than 2* Toughness Bonus. Heals 1 point of damage naturally per day, doubled if receiving (successful) medical attention. First aid heals medic's Int Bonus points.

Heavily Damaged: Total does not exceed wounds score. Heal naturally 1 point of damage per week. Medical attention doubles this. First aid heals 1 point.

Critical Hits: Total exceeds wounds score. No natural healing. With medical attention, heals 1 point per week. First aid heals 1 point.

Answer (score 7):

Taken from the [Deathwatch living eratta](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/deathwatch/news/faq/Deathwatch%20Living%20Errata%20v1-1.pdf):

> **Question:** How does Medicae skill’s First Aid option work  when
>   multiple injuries are received and some are treated  successfully and
>   others are treated unsuccessfully?
>
> **Answer:** First Aid is applied to all
>   Damage that the character  has taken and that has not been treated
>   yet. A single application  of First Aid treats all Damage taken, even
>   if it came from  multiple sources. If the First Aid was unsuccessful,
>   or if it did  not restore all Damage, the player should note the
>   remaining  Damage as being ‘Treated’ – thereafter it can only be
>   treated  with Extended Care Medicae Option or natural healing. For 
>   example: A Battle-Brother has 20 Wounds and is completely  uninjured.
>   He suffers 10 Damage leaving him with 10  Wounds. First Aid is applied
>   and heals 8 Damage, the Space  Marine now has 18 Wounds, and 2 points
>   of Treated Damage.  The Space Marine suffers another 10 Damage leaving
>   him  with 8 Wounds, 10 points of Untreated Damage, and 2 points  of
>   Treated Damage. First Aid is applied and heals 12 Damage,  which would
>   normally put the Space Marine right back up  to 20 Wounds; however,
>   because 2 points of Damage have  already been treated, the Space
>   Marine only heals 10 points  of Damage (that were Untreated) and now
>   has 18 Wounds.  The Battle-Brother still has 2 points of Treated
>   Damage that  have not been healed and would need to rely on Extended 
>   Care or natural healing to recover these 2 points of Damage.

Comment: This ought to be marked correct by OP, considering it references official game errata rather than house rules, logical though they may be.